# Can't mount Windows drive

Tags: mount

Can't mount Windows drives, I see this error:
[image: Error message]

Whenever I try to click Data or OS label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens, because Windows 8 is not turning off computer completely, but it is more like hibernation - it saves the disk state and computer can boot faster. Hibernation "locks" the disk so we have to disable fastboot, which is reason why Windows 8 doesn't turn off properly.

In Windows, go to Control Panel, Hardware and Sound, Power Options and select "**Choose what the power buttons do**"
[image: Choose what the power buttons do]

Then click on "**Change settings that are currently unavalible**"
[image: Change settings that are currently unavalible]

and uncheck "**Turn on fast startup**"
[image: Turn on fast startup (recommended)]

Don't just turn Windows off, **turn it off and back on**. And then turn it off (Helped in my case).

Also, you could try disabling hibernation mode by typing `powercfg /h off` in cmd.exe with administrator permissions.